# Copy vendor folder via ftp

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, composer-php

I have created a `laravel 7` application and copied the folder via `ftp` to the shared host for testing.

After configuring all database details, I try to open my application, however I get:

```
Warning: require(/usr/www/users/test_project/vendor/composer/../infyomlabs/laravel-generator/src/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/www/users/test_project/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 69

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/usr/www/users/test_project/vendor/composer/../infyomlabs/laravel-generator/src/helpers.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php/') in /usr/www/users/test_project/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 69
```

I was guessing that there might be a problem with my `composer.lock` file. However, I do not yet have ssh access to my shared hosting.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What have you tried to check the code for errors? If you have FTP access, you can browse each and every file to check for problems

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to run `composer dumpautoload` if you have ssh access. That will allow composer to rewrite the auto load files relative to the directory it is in now.

Comment: Shared host for testing often does not have ssh access.